# What purpose did Jaime have in the Battle of Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Long Night" did Jaime have any impact on the course of the battle or the main characters? Brienne defended him in front of Daenerys and the Starks in the episode prior and Bran acknowledges their last meeting and let's him off the hook but for what purpose? Jaime has done nothing to prevent the battle of King's Landing or fulfilled any action that seems worthy of being forgiven for all his prior misdemeanours.

Comment: My theory is that the show writers have an outline from what Martin planned for the books and are just checking events off of a list, and to hell with reaching them organically.

Comment: Jaime has had no purpose for 6 seasons, given the way that he died

Comment: @alec_a He has a narrative purpose though. He is on the path to redemption, which is cut short because he cannot fight his own nature. So he dies in the arms of his sister, who he was destined to live this world with. I dunno, it works for me thematically, even if he doesn't achieve any *practical* result.

Comment: @AndesF. I'd say a well-written story generally tries to make sure its events and characters are interconnected, even it waits until the end for them all to work in tandem. I certainly thought there would be a bit more oomph to the Jaime storyline. Kinda hope the books will be different in that regard.

Comment: I don't understand this idea that a major character *has* to have some kind of fairytale destiny and save the day. Why? "In war, people die all the time". If he had rode into King's Landing on a shining steed with Brienne fighting by his side, and slain Cersei painlessly with one hand while defending the innocent with the other non-hand, pausing only to quip a witty one-liner, the exact same people complaining about his character arc now would be (rightly) complaining about "fan service" and "plot armour".

Comment: @user568458 I'm not a s08 hater just assumed there was going to be more of a link and character arch for him, also we don't actually know if Jaime and Cersi are dead yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst [amflare's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212528/58193) gets to the heart of it:

- He had Widow's Wail a Valyrian steel sword that is top notch for fighting White Walkers and their wights.
- He is a good fighter, one of the most renowned in all of the Seven Kingdoms, a knight and a former member of the Kingsguard. Even without his right hand he can still give others a run for their money.
- They needed every body possible, there and one as good as Jaime is too good of an opportunity to miss.

In the scale of the battle it's safe to say that he would have chopped down a large amount of wights defending Winterfell.

However, there's another main point, Jaime is a good battle commander and leader. Whilst Brienne was in immediate charge of the flank held by the Arryns, Jaime is a commanding presence. He's been shown to be a strong leader and a half decent battle commander, he's the sort you'd want as a second in command on the field to help organise the troops. In fact if I'm remembering correctly I think he does give orders or relays orders down the lines in the chaos which is very useful in the heat of the conflict.

Answer (score 12):

It can be argued that no one had an impact on that battle aside from Arya. The Night King was rolling them all up pretty neatly.

As for Jamie's individual contribution though, he was a reasonably competent fighter with a Valyrian steel sword, something that is quite helpful when fighting White Walkers.

Daenerys and the Starks let him off the hook because they needed every living body they could possibly get to assist in the fight.

Comment: Jamie gave his sword Oathkeeper (Eddard Stark's reforged 'Ice') to Brienne both in the books and the show. Unless he found Widow's Wail somewhere (belonged to Joffrey), he has no Valyrian steel..

Comment: He has been wearing Widow's Wail since Season 7. He received it sometime between returning from the Riverlands and the Sack of Highgarden. We know for sure because Olenna Tyrell commented on it.

Comment: Okay. That never happened in the books though.

Comment: @Amarth Lots of things in the show didn't happen in the books, because the show has both changed things and progressed past the point of the story the books cover. What exactly is the point of bringing that up?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Obviously, the point is to explain why I made my previous comment.